# Don't understand this unfamiliar syntax: arr1[ arr2[i] - 'a' ]++

Tags: c, frequency

I am looking at a program that finds the frequency of strings entered. Comparison is made based on a string's ASCII value against the ASCII value of lowercase 'a'. I have implemented it; it works, albeit, with a bug, but essentially, I am ignorant of a particular line of code;

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(arr2); i++)
{
    // this line...
    arr1[ arr2[i] - 'a' ]++;
}
```

arr1 is `arr1[26] = {0}`,
that is, all the letters of the alphabet are assigned an index and the array is initialised to zero, while `arr2[]` as a function argument, receives the stdin.

How does the mysterious line of code work and what is it saying?

The full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
    
#define ALEPH   26
    
void freq(char arr2[]);
    
int main ()
{
    char * str;
    
    printf("\nCharacter Frequency\n"
    "--------------------\n");
    
    // user input
    printf("\nEnter a string of characters:\n");
    fgets(str, ALEPH, stdin);
    
    freq(str);
    
    return 0;
}
    
// Function Definiton
void freq (char arr2[])
{
    // array for ascii characters initialised to 0
    int arr1[ALEPH] = {0};
    
    // scan and cycle through the input array
    for  (int i = 0; i < strlen(arr2); i++)
    {
         arr1[ arr2[i] - 'a' ]++;
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
    {
        if ( arr1[j] != 0 )
        {
            printf("\nCharacter: %c - Frequency: %d", 'a'+j, arr1[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll get undefined behavior if the string contains any characters other than 'a' through 'z'.

Comment: Do you understand `arr2[i]`? Do you understand `'a'`? Do you understand `(something) - (something)`? Do you understand `arr1[(something)]`? Do you understand `(something)++`? Then you understand `arr1[ arr2[i] - 'a']++`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I understand all that you've shown; no, I don't fully comprehend the logic of the statement.

Comment: @RaymondChen If only understanding the building blocks meant we understood everything built from them. Subtracting `'a'` to convert a letter to an index is a particularly clever trick that isn't obvious to all new programmers despite subtraction being a familiar friend.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yes, I gather that ASCII 'a' is somehow responsible for establishing what the other characters are, but I don't know how exactly, it does that.

Comment: Look at the [numeric values assigned to each character in ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) and you'll probably understand.

Comment: "Subtracting 'a' to convert a letter to an index" work for the ubiquitous ASCII, but not archaic EBCIDIC. C does not specify ASCII.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for the suggestion. RemyLebeau has clarified this logic, for which, I am grateful. I suppose I could start playing with the code and substitute Hexadecimal code values for ASCII (where there is a difference of 12 for all characters), but that might be pushing the boat out a tad too far.

Comment: @chux Thank you for the information. Obviously, I'll have to research this.

Comment: @RaymondChen You forgot to mention that letters are consequtive in the ascii table. That's crucial to understand the code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The question wasn't "How does this work?" It was "I don't understand this unfamiliar syntax."

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for your observation on how the code works in relation to the consective ordering of each ASCII lowercase charCode. Just to be sure, are you saying that `arr2`will always be ordered (from `[0]`) a - z ? Also, respectfully, if I may correct you; I did ask how that mysterious line of code worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr1` is an array of 26 `int`s initialized to `0`s.  The indexes of its elements are `0..25`.

`arr2` is assumed to be a string of lowercase letters `'a'..'z'` only.  The characters are assumed to be using an encoding where lowercase letters are single-byte and sequential in value, such as ASCII (where `a=97`, ..., `z=122`). Anything else that does not match these assumptions will cause **undefined behavior** in this code.

The code loops through `arr2`, and for each character, calculates an index by subtracting the numeric value of `'a'` (ie, ASCII `97`) from the character's numeric value:

`'a' - 'a'` = `97 - 97` = `0`
`'b' - 'a'` = `98 - 97` = `1`
...
`'z' - 'a'` = `122 - 97` = `25`

Then the code accesses the `arr1` element at that index, and increments that element's value by 1.

Answer (score 4):

You ask about the line:

```
arr1[ arr2[i] - 'a' ]++;
```

In this line:

- arr1 is the array that will accumulate the histogram
- arr2 is the input string which will contribute to the histogram
- i is the index into input string.

This can be rewritten as:

```
ch = arr2[i];
histogram_slot = ch - 'a';
arr1[histogram_slot ] = arr1[histogram_slot ] + 1;
```

For each character in the input string, the character is fetched from the string and assigned to "ch".  "ch" is converted to the index in the histogram array by subtracting 'a'.  In the third line, the histogram_slot is increased by one.  histogram_slot 0 is incremented for 'a', 1 for 'b', 2 for 'c', ... , and 25 for 'z'.

A serious bug in this code is that it only works for the lower case letters.  An upper case letter, digit, punctuation, Unicode, extended ASCII, or any character not between 'a' and 'z' inclusive will write in an unintended region of memory.  At the best, this will cause an unexpected crash.  In the medium disaster, it will cause sporatic malfunction that gets through your testing.  In the worst case, it creates a security hole allowing someone uncontrolled access to your stack, and thus the ability to take over execution of the thread.

Comment: The OP indicated that there was a bug.  I was expanding on the OP's comment to show where the bug may have been.  There was no specification that would allow one to assume a limited range.  iMO, it is a bug to not handle the full range of values.  My first law of programming is: "If it takes more than three sentences to explain why it works, it doesn't.'